# Python (naive) shuffle in place -- towards reproducing Fisher-Yates

Tags: python, shuffle

I am trying to reproduce the Fisher-Yates algorithm for shuffling an array in place:

- [ref1: Coding Horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/the-danger-of-naivete.html)
- [ref2: Eli Bendersky](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/05/28/the-intuition-behind-fisher-yates-shuffling/)

The problem is that when I run the first step for a "naive" shuffle, my results come up very even; I do not see the skew expected for some of the combinations. I have run up to 6 million trials:

- 123 --> 999,472 (16.7%)
- 132 --> 999,588 (16.7%)
- 213 --> 1,000,883 (16.7%)
- 231 --> 1,001,306 (16.7%)
- 312 --> 999,702 (16.7%)
- 321 --> 999,049 (16.7%)
- **TOT --> 6,000,000 (100.0%)**

I suspect there is something "wrong" with my implementation and would appreciate feedback.

Here is the code I am using:

```
import random
from pprint import pprint

runLength = 600000

cards = [1, 2, 3]
sequenceCount = {'123':0, '132':0, '213':0, '231':0, '312':0, '321':0}

for k in range(runLength):

    # naive shuffle
    for i,v in enumerate(cards):
        n = random.randint(0, len(cards)-1)
        cards[i], cards[n] = cards[n], cards[i] #swap

    # track results
    strDeck = ''
    for j,v in enumerate(cards):
        strDeck = strDeck + str(cards[j])
    sequenceCount[strDeck] = sequenceCount[strDeck] + 1

# results summary
pprint(sequenceCount)
```

Comment: @Bill you missed the ṕoint, he wants to test the defective algorithm

Comment: Read the provided link

Comment: @Bill: 1000 more is not skew when the sample size is 6 million; that is completely statistically insignificant. The point is not to artificially create skew with a small sample size, either

Comment: based on Antti's response, I see now that the main problem was that "cards = [1, 2, 3]" lies outside the for loop. Moving it inside (so that the list is re-initialized for each trial) generates the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahha, the problem is that you reshuffle the cards again and again, instead of always using the `[ 1, 2, 3 ]` as the starting point. Moreover your python is very unidiomatic and a bit hard to read, so let me rewrite it for you ;)

```
import random
from pprint import pprint
from collections import Counter

runLength = 600000

sequenceCount = Counter()
originalCards = ["1", "2", "3"]
ncards = len(originalCards)

for k in range(runLength): # use xrange on python 2
    cards = list(originalCards)

    # naive shuffle        
    for i in range(ncards):
        n = random.randint(0, ncards - 1)
        cards[i], cards[n] = cards[n], cards[i] #swap

    sequenceCount[''.join(cards)] += 1

# results summary
print(sequenceCount)

# result: Counter({'132': 111424, '231': 111194, '213': 110312, 
#                  '123': 89533, '321': 88846, '312': 88691})
```

Comment: Thank you! I also really appreciate you taking the time to 'python' my code.

Comment: @Roberto, to use Python effectively for such simulations and writing algorithms you should quickly browse the `itertools`, `functools`, `heapq` and `collections` module documentation, many of the things such as the `Counter` class are there already, no need to reinvent.